# angular not convert json dates with [UTC]

Tags: java, json, angular, rest

I am building an Angular 7 app that consumes a java REST API for its data. The API delivers some date information in JSON form:
***{
      "date_c": "2019-03-10T06:00:00Z[UTC]",
      "state": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Charles Brown ",
      "provider": "clar"
    }***

so in Angular when im trying to use
**const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);**

it display an error , i find out that the problem is in the symbols '[' and ']' of the [UTC],
   how can i remove it so it can work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Use slice pipe to truncate [UTC] before date formatting.

```
{{value | slice : 0:20| date:'d/M/yy, h:mm a' }}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: hi, yes i tryied to simplify , this is how i have it in the html component :  **<ngx-datatable-column name="Date" prop="date_c" [flexGrow]="2">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      {{value | date:'d/M/yy, h:mm a'}}
    </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>**  , and the error in the web console is : **Unable to convert "2019-03-10T06:00:00Z[UTC]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe**

Comment: I tried to convert this date into an actual date object and I see Invalid Date error due to [UTC]. so I tried to truncate [UTC] by using Slice pipe and it works. Use this {{value | slice : 0:20| date:'d/M/yy, h:mm a' }}